# Rails: Specifying association type when saving tokens using collection_singular_ids=ids method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Below are my models. To describe it in words, a 'Show' has 'Crew'. 'Crew' is made up of 'People'. Association between 'Show' and 'People' in 'Crew' can be either of type 'Actor' or 'Other'.
I have tokens coming in from a autocomplete UI on 'Show' form where 'People' are filled in either 'Actor' field, or 'Other' field.

QUESTION:
In the `actor_tokens=(ids)` and `actor_tokens=(ids)` methods in the 'Show' model, where i am saving the tokens coming in, How do I save the relationships as 'actor' or 'other'??

All associations saved from `actor_tokens=(ids)` should be of type 'actor' and
All associations saved from `other_tokens=(ids)` should be of type 'other' and

I am looking for a elegant solution to match the use of *collection_singular_ids=ids* to save my tokens.

> Crew Model

```
class Crew < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :person

  attr_accessor  :type    #this can be 'actor'  'other' string

end
```

> Person Model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
          attr_accessible :first_name, :handle, :last_name
          has_many :crews
          has_many :shows, :through => :crews

        end
```

> Show Model

```
 class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :handle, :name, :crew_tokens
      has_many :crews
      has_many :people, :through => :crews

      attr_reader :actor_tokens

      def actor_tokens=(ids)
        self.person_ids = ids.split(",")
            #----->associate tokens coming in here as type = 'actor'
      end

      def other_tokens=(ids)
        self.person_ids = ids.split(",")
            #----->associate tokens coming in here as type = 'other'
      end

    end
```

PS: Please suggest a better title for this post!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `collection_singular_ids=` to create new `Crew` instances the way you're wanting. [`ids_writer`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L57) accepts only a list of valid, already existing ids; you can't specify other attributes through this method.

Instead you can build the `Crew` instances, specifying the `:person_id` and `:type` as necessary, and associate them back to the instance of `Show`.

```
def actor_tokens(ids)
  create_crews_from_ids(ids, :actor)
end

def other_tokens=(ids)
  create_crews_from_ids(ids, :other)
end

  private

  def create_crews_from_ids(ids, type)
    ids = ids.split(",").each do |id|
      crews.create({ person_id: id, type: type })
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is not working. I get an error 'You cannot call create unless the parent is saved'!

Comment: You'd have to use `new` instead of `create` to deal with a `Show` that's not persisted.

Comment: but then how will that affect future updates? suppose the record is updated and saved what happens to old tokens?